# Anonymous function parameter information is incorrect

Tags: php, parameters, closures

I need to write code according to the parameters of an anonymous function. The following code gives the parameters correctly.

Example code 1:

```
class test{

}

$func = function($a, $b, test $t, $c = 'new') {
    echo 'test function ran'.PHP_EOL;
};

$info = new ReflectionFunction($func);

var_dump(
    $info->getName(), 
    $info->getNumberOfParameters(), 
    $info->getNumberOfRequiredParameters()
);
```

result var_dump

```
string(9) "{closure}"
int(4)
int(3)
```

The result is different when I change the parameter order. Do you have any information on this?

Example code 2:

```
class test{

}

$func = function($a, $b, $c = 'new', test $t ) {
    echo 'test function ran'.PHP_EOL;
};

$info = new ReflectionFunction($func);

var_dump(
    $info->getName(), 
    $info->getNumberOfParameters(), 
    $info->getNumberOfRequiredParameters()
);
```

result var_dump

```
string(9) "{closure}"
int(4)
int(4)
```

I am sorry, my English is not good. I hope I can tell.

--- UPDATE --
Thank you for the answers. I get it now.
[image]

Comment: The second example is good too. When calling the function you cannot omit the `$c` parameter... is a required parameter. you cannot call `$func(1,2,$objTest)`; you must assign a parameter to `$c` like `$func(1,2,null, $objTest)`

Comment: $c has a default value. Why is this required? Because the object came first?

Comment: `$c` is required because the 4th argument is required. You can't do `$func(1, 2, $t)` because `$t` would then be the 3rd argument.